# Generating Two Numbers With a Specific Sum

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I'm trying to generate two numbers with a specific sum. Here is my proposed method:

Edited: http://jsfiddle.net/KDmwn/274/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function GenerateRandomNumber() {
        var min = -13, max = 13;
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;   
        return random;
    }

    var x = GenerateRandomNumber(); 

    function GenerateRandomNumber2() {
        var min2 = -13, max2 = 13;
        var random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max2 - min2 + 1)) + min2;   
        if ((random2 + x) == 0){
            return random2};
    }

var xx = GenerateRandomNumber2();
```

There's something wrong with the `if ((random2 + x) = 0)` line, as the code runs perfectly fine when it's removed. How can I modify this line so that the sum of the two numbers is 0? It would be most helpful if someone could modify the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KDmwn/273/) that I've included. Thanks!

Comment: ReferenceError: sum is not defined
http://fiddle.jshell.net/KDmwn/273/show/
Row: 74

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know how to fix it. I'm a complete novice (as my post may make clear ha). Would you mind helping me in the right direction for fixing that?

Comment: You should really obey whitespace nesting practices... you will avoid many bugs doing this.

Comment: Your fiddle does not match the question

Comment: in fiddle you never return `sum`?

Comment: I apologize for the naive question, but how would the `sum` look different from the ` if ((random2 + x) == 0)` I thought that is what did the sum.

Comment: What do you want to do if `(random2 + x) == 0` is not satisfied? Return a 0?

Comment: this statement `$('#y').html(sum);` in your fiddle has a variable that is never assigned...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to make it *only* output a second number that, when added to the first, equals 0? Because it actually already does that - but only if it gets it on the first try (try hitting refresh at least 30 times.) You need to tell it to keep re-choosing (looping) the second random number while the sum isn't 0:

```
function GenerateRandomNumber2() {
    var min2 = -13,
        max2 = 13;
    var random2;
    while ((random2 + x) !== 0) {
        random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max2 - min2 + 1)) + min2;
    }
    return random2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vL77hjp0/

---

To take this one step further, if I'm reading this right (if not ignore this) it looks like you might want to eventually choose a random *sum* and have it determine the required second number to be added. To do this, we would replace the 0 in our "while" loop with 'sum'. And 'sum' would have to be defined as a random number with a "max=x+13" and "min=x-13" (otherwise the random number may be too high/low for random2 to *ever* reach, causing the browser to crash.) [Or just remove the limits from random2.]

http://jsfiddle.net/fkuo54hc/

Comment: In that case, returning `-x` would make more sense.

Comment: This is an awesome answer. Thanks, Sam!

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid:

```
if ((random2 + x) = 0){
```

You cannot assign something to an expression.

You probably meant to use the comparison operator (`==`), like this:

```
if ((random2 + x) == 0){
```

Comment: Even with the double == it doesn't work. I updated the JsFiddle to include the ==. Would you be willing to take a look at that JsFiddle and see if it needs any tweaking? I have been trying to figure this out for hours haha.

Answer (score 0):

First, your `GenerateRandomNumbers2` function returns undefined value other than in your if statement. So you need to return a value. I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KDmwn/275/) and refactor some of your code.

Comment: Thanks, Kazupooot!